# Как определить наличие кластеров в серии 1-D данных?

Tags: математика, статистика

Для небольших наборов timestamp требуется определить, распределены ли они относительно случайно, или кучкуются около отдельных временных точек?

Курс статистики забыт. Наверное, есть какая-то мера равномерности распределения точек вдоль одной оси?

Например:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
// k = 0, идеально равномерно

B = [1, 2.92, 2.95, 2.96, 2.98, 3.05, 3.07, 6.9, 6.95, 6.99, 7.01, 10];
// 1 > k > 0, кластеры около примерно x=3 и x=7

C = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5];
// k = 1, 100%-плотный кластер в x=5
```

Как определить меру рассеянности данных? Делать планирую на JS, но язык/среда не принципиальны – понять бы принцип решения.

Comment: "Гуглите" - метод ближайшего соседа

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов ML – это модно, спортивно, современно. Вот только нет обучающего набора данных. Тут, мне интуитивно кажется, задача проще: что-то со свёрткой (convolution) или running mean. Данные отсортированы. Пробежаться вдоль оси "окном", считая, сколько попадает в него событий. Взять пики. Попробовать несколько разных размеров "окна".

Comment: Для применения метода ближайшего соседа не нужна обучающая выборка. Он прост, как веник. Его недостаток, проблемы с начальным определением числа кластеров и чувствительность к этому параметру. Если же стоит задачи найти локальные пики в зашумленной последовательности - то да свертка по любому оконному фильтру с этим справится

Answer (score 1):

Можно предложить эмпирический критерий вида
С(n - 1)<sup>2</sup>D<sub>A</sub> < (n<sub>A</sub> - 1)<sup>2</sup>D,
где A - тестируемая подвыборка.

Критерий чувствителен к неравномерности данных уже при С = 1, но при желании можно выбрать другое значение.